# Running pg_dump from another machine

Tags: c#, postgresql, iis, pg-dump

The program which I have on IIS is working normally and connected to Postgre db in another server .Now,I want to get a backup from one of its tables.The problem is here that I can't run a pg_dump from a remote server because pg_dump is not exist in server that program is running .I looked for it and found out it's possible to do by ssh tunnel although I couldn't resolve it and had wild goose chase.In the other hand,I want to get remote backup from postgre db table that is not in current server and also pg_dump  is in another machine.
In additional,I coded on c#.
Is there anybody to help me ?

Comment: One thing you can try is making the folder where the database file is located shared.  Then you can access the file remotely from another machine and archive.  Most archive utilities do the access from the database file and not the service.

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple.

Install the PostgreSQL client on the machine where you want to perform the backup, then you have a `pg_dump` executable.

Comment: I can't do that,I'm working on a project in which the location of main project is separated from its DB so I can't use pg_dump in the same machine.

Comment: You misunderstood me. `pg_dump` doesn't have to run on the database server, it is a client tool. You can install it anywhere.

Comment: Aha,you mean I can backup and restore db from other machine when only pg_dump installed on local machine? without postgresql service or pgadmin or any dependencies ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The only dependency is `libpq`, the PostgreSQL client shared library.

Comment: It seems its dependencies more than one dll bkz I downloaded that and it didn't work and needed some new Dlls.

Comment: Yes, of course. I meant `libpq` is the only PostgreSQL dependency. You could build a minimal PostgreSQL client from source that has as few dependencies as possible. The easiest is to install the PostgreSQL client from a binary installation package.

Comment: I'll try that although I don't have any permission to install postgresql.By the way, I appreciate you .